# How can I align multiple times in the 'flalign' environment?

Tags: align

I am following the solution in *[How to additionally name equations in align environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683720/how-to-additionally-name-equations-in-align-environment/683732#683732)* to name my own equations. I would now like to align them at the `=` sign and the text `where`, but I am not getting it right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \phantom{(\mathrm{elf})\ (2)} && % balance out width of descriptor
  \alpha_i^t &= asd \quad\text{where}\quad i \in [1,...,n]
  &&
  (\mathrm{elf})\label{eq:attentionhead1}\\
  \phantom{(\mathrm{elf})\ (2)} && % balance out width of descriptor
  \alpha_i^t &= g\Bigl(\frac{u}{v}\Bigr) \quad\text{where}\quad i \in [1,...,n]
  &&
  (\mathrm{clf})\label{eq:attentionhead2}
  %\label{eq:attentionhead1}
\end{flalign}

\ref{eq:attentionhead1} \ref{eq:attentionhead2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to follow the solution in *[Aligning equations with text with alignat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/aligning) equations-with-text-with-alignat*, but it did not work.

```
 \begin{flalignat*}{3}
...
 \end{flalignat*}{3}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would keep the basic `flalign` setup, as it makes it straightforward to place the equation descriptors at the far right, immediately next to the equation number. To achieve alignment on the words "where", I suggest you (a) measure the width of the widest element to the right of the `=` symbols and (b) place the material in the shorter elements in a `\mybox` "box", as is described in more detail in the code given below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newlength\mylen
% measure width of widest element to the right of the '=' symbols
\settowidth\mylen{$\displaystyle g\Bigl(\frac{u}{v}\Bigr)$}
% define a utility macro:
\newcommand\mybox[1]{\parbox{\mylen}{$\displaystyle #1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \phantom{(\mathrm{elf})\ (2)} % balance out width of descriptor
  &&
  \alpha_i^t &= \mybox{asd} 
  \quad\text{where $i\in[1,\dots,n]$}
  &&
  (\mathrm{elf}) % equation descriptor
  \label{eq:attentionhead1} \\
  % balancing need not be repeated in second row
  && 
  \alpha_i^t &= g\Bigl(\frac{u}{v}\Bigr) 
  \quad\text{where $i\in[1,\dots,n]$}
  &&
  (\mathrm{clf}) % equation descriptor
  \label{eq:attentionhead2}
\end{flalign}
Cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:attentionhead1} 
and \eqref{eq:attentionhead2}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Mico's answer can be automated using functionality from [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox). `\eqmathbox[<tag>][<align>]{<stuff>}` below is an extension to that package's `\eqmakebox` that sets `<stuff>` in the widest box possible across similar `<tag>`s with the optional localised `<align>`ment (default is `c`entred).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,eqparbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34412/5764
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqmathbox}{o O{c} m}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox[#1][#2]{$##1##2$}}}
    {\def\eqmathbox@##1##2{\eqmakebox{$##1##2$}}}
  \mathpalette\eqmathbox@{#3}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \phantom{(\mathrm{elf})\ \eqref{eq:attentionhead1}} % balance out width of descriptor
  &&
  \alpha_i^t &= \eqmathbox[asd][l]{asd} 
  \quad\text{where $i\in[1,\dots,n]$}
  &&
  (\mathrm{elf}) % equation descriptor
  \label{eq:attentionhead1} \\
  % balancing need not be repeated in second row
  && 
  \alpha_i^t &= \eqmathbox[asd]{g\Bigl(\frac{u}{v}\Bigr)}
  \quad\text{where $i\in[1,\dots,n]$}
  &&
  (\mathrm{clf}) % equation descriptor
  \label{eq:attentionhead2}
\end{flalign}
Cross-references to equations \eqref{eq:attentionhead1} 
and \eqref{eq:attentionhead2}.

\end{document}
```